# My Google Appscript is Not Working Because of the GetUser (I Guess...)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var xCol = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var xRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();

  if ( xCol == 2 && sheet.getName() =='Çeviri' ) {
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername(); 
    sheet.getRange(xRow, 7).setValue(user); 
    }
  }
```

This script's purpose is; in Google Docs Excel, when a user change a cell in column B in sheet "Çeviri", it writes that users name 7 horizontal cells away.
It's working though, in some way.
When document's owner changes a cell in column B, app sees it and runs. But when another user changes a cell in column B, app doesn't see it and doesn't run.
I think it's about Google, I guess they changed policies and because of that I can't get any other users name with this script
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getuser

So my question is, is there any way to write this app without "getUser" command? Because I think it's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, Google no longer allows scripts that run in an `onEdit()` context to find the identity of the user at the keyboard. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()):

> *the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, **these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Workspace domain as the user**.*

In other words, if you are in a Google Workspace domain, you *can* discover the identity of the user at the keyboard and put their email address in a column.

It is best to ask users to authorize the script before running, which can be done with a custom menu item. See the [insertActiveUserEmailAddressInColumn_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/29026160?hl=en&msgid=29371236) script for sample code.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I get it and I tried but I'm not so good at this, so I couldn't get this thing done. Is there any chanse you could help me a little more? I'm not sure which codes I need to debug or delete to make it work with my own code. I just need that authorization system so my script can work. If you could tell me or show me which codes should I delete or edit, I'll be so thankful.

Comment: The sample code I linked has the full functionality you are asking for, so one option would be to just use the sample code instead of trying to make your own code work.  Make sure you are using version 1.1 rather than 1.2, and set the parameters in the script before running it. The sample code contains full step-to-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it this way

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && sh.getName() == 'Çeviri') {
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 7).setValue(user);
  }
}

    function creattrigger() {
      if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyEdit").length == 0) {
        ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
      }
    }
```

Run the create trigger function.  It's setup so that you can't create more than one.

Comment: Thank you, but gave an error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onMyEdit

Comment: I hope you  realize that you cannot call these onEdit functions from the script editor without supplying the event object. You have to save them and then go to the page and make the appropriate edits. I often use `e.source.toast("flags");` to help me to debug these functions

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know these stuff so much. I just needed this code to work properly because it's part of my job and I needed this.
I am really trying to understand, could you please tell me what should I do? I can't understand your programmer language. Do I need to edit a variable in this? Or something else?

Comment: I told you what to do in the comment above.  Just save the code and go to the sheet in question and make the appropriate edits and see if the function performs properly.

Comment: I did the appropriate changes but script doesn't work anymore. It doesn't write anyone's username now. Am I missing something?